# Excel VBA Auto Sort with Manual Calculation

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a workbook with quite a few array formulas active so I've turned off auto-calculate in order to allow for some smaller formulas to run more quickly. This necessitates me adding VBA code to call for some ranges to calculate based off of certain conditions.

I currently have some formulas in a range that will blank them out should a value appear in a drop down list, this is my workaround to for an auto.filter that can filter out more than two criteria.

My issue at the moment is I'd like to be able to adjust the drop down list to put blanks at the end of the list (ie, filter descending Z-A), but I can't figure out how to combine .Sort with .Calculate.

TL:DNR have manual calculations turned on, need VBA to trigger calculate after formulas run in a range to auto sort decending.

```
    If Target.Address = "$F$19" Then                               
        Sheets("DO NOT DELETE").Range("P3:P33").Calculate          'Calculating formulas in range
                Range("P3", Range("P3").End(xlDown)).Sort Key1:=Range("P3"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
'Data set begins on P3 with a header in P2
        Sheets("DO NOT DELETE").Range("P3:P33").Calculate
```

When a value is selected in F19 the formula in P3:P33 run without issue, but things are not then auto sorted...

My Idea was to add another .Calculate instruction so that it would hopefully do the sorting but no dice.

I've also tried writing the code in this fashion in case I had written it wrong above (though
I didn't get any errors with it)

```
Sheets("DO NOT DELETE").Range("VAL_TECHNOLOGY").Sort Key1:=Range("P2"), Order1:=xlDescending
```

This returns a 1004 Run Time Error saying the sort reference is not valid.

If anyone could offer some guidance I'd be very appreciative.

Thanks

Comment: Your 1004 comes from the fact the range you specify as `key1` is not qualified, so it is taken from the active sheet, not from sheet `DO NOT DELETE`.

Comment: Ahhhh, that fixed it, and it's updating correctly now! Thanks for taking a look and helping out, sincerely!